# Save wxWindow as wxBitmap on Retina display not working

Tags: wxwidgets

I am trying to take a screenshot of a window. I have used the following code.

```
wxClientDC bgdc(this);

int width = bgdc.GetSize().GetWidth();
int height = bgdc.GetSize().GetHeight();

//Create a Bitmap that will later on hold the screenshot image
//Note that the Bitmap must have a size big enough to hold the screenshot
//-1 means using the current default colour depth
wxBitmap bmpWin = wxBitmap(m_width, m_height, -1);

wxMemoryDC memDC;
memDC.SelectObject(bmpWin);
memDC.Blit(0, 0, width, height, &bgdc, 0, 0);

wxASSERT(bmpWin.IsOk());
```

This code works perfectly under Windows.
On Mac I am facing the issue. Captured bitmap is zoomed (by 2x) and goes out of width and height value, hence clipped.

I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

Note* This is happening on Retina display only

Comment: Which version of wxWidgets are you using? Better support for high DPI is established as of wxWidgets 3.1.0

Comment: @macroland I am using wxWIdgets 3.0 on MacOS and It is not feasible to upgrade to 3.1